# search sub-string from backward using Python

Tags: python, string

Wondering if there is a neat API in Python to search a string from backward (from a specific position in a string), for example, in string "Hello StackOverflow Hello Python", suppose I want to find the index of sub-string "Hello" which is previous to sub-string "Python"?

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Downvoted. First result for "python string" search gives you https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rfind

Comment: @viraptor, nice catch. I am confused by rindex and rfind, which one is for my problem? Thanks.

Comment: Either one. The question is - do you want an exception thrown (rindex) or -1 returned (rfind) if the strings are missing.

Comment: @viraptor, I just need to get -1 when there is no hit, whether Exception is returned or not is not important, your recommendations are highly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's called [`str.rindex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.rindex#str.rindex). It takes arguments `sub` - a substring to look for, `start` - a starting position, and `end`.

It is the `r`everse of the `index` function. There are some others, like `rsplit`, too.

Comment: Thanks Austin, always good to learn from you. Just to clarify, do you mean using rindex or using rfind? :)

Comment: That's up to you. Do you want a `ValueError`? But for your information, the `index` and `rindex` functions appear in a *lot* of languages, so they're a good pair to remember.

Comment: Hi Austin, I just need to get -1 when there is no hit, whether ValueError is returned or not is not important, your recommendations are highly appreciated. :)

Comment: Thanks for all the help, Austin. Mark your reply as answered.